# Creating dataset for survival analysis

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am trying to perform survival analysis using survival package in R.

I have the dataset that looks like this and can be created with the foloowing code.

```
event <- c(1,0,0,1,0,1)
time <-c(8,50,100,200,300, 1)
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5, 6)
sex<-c(1,0,1,0,1,0)
mydat <- data.frame(id, time, event)


library(survival)
library(survminer)
fit<-survfit(Surv(time,event)~sex, mydat)
ggsurvplot(fit, size = 1, # change line size
      #palette = c("#E7B800", "#2E9FDF"), # custom color palette
        conf.int = TRUE, # Add confidence interval
        pval = TRUE, # Add p-value
        risk.table = TRUE, # Add risk table
        risk.table.col = "strata", # Risk table color by groups
 )
```

However, mydat as such does not work as input for survival analysis.

As the output looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBwPx.png)

I would appreciate any help to make it suitable for the surival analysis using survival package.

Thanks  in advance.

Comment: Could you include more of the code that you're trying to use after the creation of the data frame? It's difficult to determine what the problem is without more information.

Comment: Further detail on 
"*mydat as such does not work as input for survival analysis*" 
would be helpful.

Comment: @sam  further detials/ code included

Comment: @r.bot  further detials/ code included

Answer (score 0):

I think that your data *are* working as input for survival analysis (once the error in `sex` is corrected), I think they just don't show what you expect.

No errors are returned when doing `survfit()`, nor when plotting either survival or ggsurvplot. Either method reflects the data you have.

`summary(fit)` returns a meaningful result for your model fit:

```
summary(fit)
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, event) ~ sex, data = mydat)

                sex=0 
 time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
    1      3       1    0.667   0.272          0.3            1
  200      1       1    0.000     NaN           NA           NA

                sex=1 
        time       n.risk      n.event     survival      std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI 
       8.000        3.000        1.000        0.667        0.272        0.300        1.000
```

There are three events in your data, one at time 1 for sex == 0, one at time 8 for sex == 1 and one at time 200 for sex == 0. This is what the graph shows. The shaded confidence intervals are very broad because you have so few observations.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. number at risk by time shows 3 at time 300 whereas it should be 0 ??. as the number of events increase over the time period. or am i misinterpreting it completely?

Comment: Riz - you may be mis-reading your code or looking at an old image perhaps. The image from @r.bot above shows (and I also get) 0 and 1 at time = 300. I can't see how you got 3 and 1 as shown in your first image. Also not quite related to your question, but probably worth setting `conf.int=FALSE` in this particular case.